# The System can not find the files specifield in Mongo DB

Tags: mongodb, windows-7

I have installed successfully mongodb 3.4 on my windows 7 and set the variable path also. but in my services when I try to start the mongodb server it is occured following error message here

```
Windows could not start the MongoDB Service on Local Computer

The System cannot find the files specifield
```

how could I fix this problem

Comment: Query the service properties with `sc qc "<name of service>"`, there you get the  BINARY_PATH_NAME. Run this command from command line, it should provide more information.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit occured following message `sc is not recognized as internal or external command`

Comment: Really? Then maybe you messed up your `PATH` variable. Which folders are set there? Program `sc.exe` is located in `c:\Windows\System32` which should be in `PATH` in any case.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit did you mean system variable path? it is `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin` I have configure it

Comment: That's bad! System default folders `C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` should be always included. When you modify it, then better do it like `SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin` to append custom folders.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit did you mean may I remove `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin` and set as `SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin`

Comment: Well if your messed up PATH is currently `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin` then this would let to `C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin` which is still wrong, of course. You must restore the default folders, after that you can add custom folders.

Comment: how could I do it?

Comment: `SET PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0`. These are the minimum. Of course I cannot know, if you dropped any other folders which are also required on your system.